# Visual Studio 2017 not showing GUI icons

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface

I recently installed the newest version of Visual Studio, and when I ran it, I came to this [screen](http://www.hnng.moe/f/Tb0). So far, I tried to rollback, which just corrupted the Visual Studio install, and which to fix was to re-install the new version, which seems to be the culprit. I have also tried to copy [the image library cache file from the profile of the admin account that was used to install VS 2017 into the profile of the development account](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94502/visual-studio-2017-153-toolbar-icons-are-missing.html). This also, did not solve my problem. I did try and update my NVIDIA driver. This did not solve my issue. Can someone offer me an alternative course of action?

Comment: I've read somewhere that is caused by the wrong display drivers.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that in my post. I did update to NVIDIA's latest drivers just recently. Just for reference, my graphics card is an NVIDIA 745.

Comment: Disable hardware acceleration and try again, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2894215/you-experience-performance-issues--product-crashes--or-rendering-issue

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, my problem has still not been resolved. Here is how it looks with the suggestions above: http://www.hnng.moe/f/TW0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to completely uninstall and re-install? Sounds like your 'update' didn't work out right.

Comment: This was my solution.